# Backbone: how to render persistent views against back button and refresh for all routes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, view

For example, I have a background template view rendered with backbone view when user visits the index route. Then every event is handled by backbone and the template does persist thoughout the routes. However, when I use refresh or backbutton in other routes different than index. my template view disappears. Is there a way to have make background template view persist under any routes against refresh and back button

Edit:
  I use the routes:

```
'index' : 'render_bg_template'
```

to initialize and render the view. So I am looking for a method to have it rendered after refresh in any routes

Comment: Might need more explanation as to how this background template view works to be able to answer.

Comment: edited my question to make it more specific

Comment: Can you simply call the same method from each of your route handlers?

Comment: that would work I guess, but the code would be bloated. I wish I could catch refresh event. It could be that I am using backbone in a way that I shouldn't.

Comment: I don't think it bloats your code that much because you've factored the action into a method already. The actual function invocation will appear in every route, which makes it seem repetitive, but this is what functions are for.

Comment: yea, I think I will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could listen to the router 'route' event that gets triggered every time a route has occurred.

```
router.on("route", function(){
   //render template here
});
```

Docs: "route:[name]" (params) — Fired by the router when a specific route is matched.

Comment: that is exactly the method I wanted. Thanks

Comment: Nice - going to use this myself.